# How to update database date/time field in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have an update button that will update my database table, It seems that my datepicker is the problem, I tried parsing it in but didn't work my recent attempt is this ....(below) .... but instead of parsing in into date ... It says error in converting string into type integer. Well, the problem is clear but the parsing method I applied is not working. Thanks

```
Try

        Dim RowsAffected As Integer = 0

        con = New OleDbConnection(cs)

        con.Open()


        Dim cq As String = "UPDATE StockItem SET StockedDate=@val1, ItemName=@val2, ItemSize=@val3, Quantity=@val4 WHERE StockedDate=@find1 AND ItemName=@find2 AND ItemSize=@find3 AND Quantity=@find4;"


        cmd = New OleDbCommand(cq)

        cmd.Connection = con

        ''SQL Where
        'type
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date, "StockedDate"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemName"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find3", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemSize"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find4", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 10, "Quantity"))
        'value

        ''Dim iString As String = "2005-05-05 22:12 PM"
        ''Dim oDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(lbltemInDate.Text, "MM-dd-yyyy", Nothing)
        ''MsgBox(oDate.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters("@find1").Value = lbltemInDate.Value.Date
        'CDate(Format(lbltemInDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy"))
        cmd.Parameters("@find2").Value = Trim(lbltemInItem.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@find3").Value = Trim(lbltemInItemSize.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@find4").Value = Val(lbltemInQuantity.Text)



        ''SQL Set
        'type
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date, "StockedDate"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemName"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val3", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemSize"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val4", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 10, "Quantity"))
        'value
        'cmd.Parameters("@val1").Value = CDate(Format(dtptemInDate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy"))
        cmd.Parameters("@val1").Value = dtptemInDate.Value.Date
        cmd.Parameters("@val2").Value = Trim(cbxtemInNewItem.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@val3").Value = Trim(cbxtemInNewItemSize.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@val4").Value = Val(txttemInNewQuantity.Text)

        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val1", dtptemInDate.Value.Date)
        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val2", cbxtemInNewItem.Text)
        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val3", cbxtemInNewItemSize.Text)
        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val3", Val(txttemInNewQuantity.Text))

        RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If RowsAffected > 0 Then

            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated!", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            iteminClearDetails()

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No record found", "Sorry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

                con.Close()
            End If

            con.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

This is the Reordered part

```
''SQL Set
        'type
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.DBDate, "StockedDate"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemName"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val3", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemSize"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val4", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 10, "Quantity"))

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.DBDate, "StockedDate"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemName"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find3", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemSize"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find4", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 10, "Quantity"))

        'value
        'cmd.Parameters("@val1").Value = CDate(Format(dtptemInDate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy"))
        cmd.Parameters("@val1").Value = dtptemInDate.Value.Date
        cmd.Parameters("@val2").Value = Trim(cbxtemInNewItem.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@val3").Value = Trim(cbxtemInNewItemSize.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@val4").Value = Val(txttemInNewQuantity.Text)


        ''SQL Where
        'type
                   'value

        ''Dim iString As String = "2005-05-05 22:12 PM"
        ''Dim oDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(lbltemInDate.Text, "MM-dd-yyyy", Nothing)
        ''MsgBox(oDate.ToString())
        Dim date1 As Date
        date1 = Date.Parse(Format("MM/dd/yyyy", lbltemInDate.Value))
        cmd.Parameters("@find1").Value = lbltemInDate.Value
        'CDate(Format(lbltemInDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy"))
        cmd.Parameters("@find2").Value = Trim(lbltemInItem.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@find3").Value = Trim(lbltemInItemSize.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@find4").Value = Val(lbltemInQuantity.Text)


        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val1", dtptemInDate.Value.Date)
        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val2", cbxtemInNewItem.Text)
        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val3", cbxtemInNewItemSize.Text)
        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val3", Val(txttemInNewQuantity.Text))
```

Does System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.DBDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", "StockedDate" ... work on .net?

The working part

```
''SQL Set
        'type
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemName"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val3", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemSize"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val4", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 10, "Quantity"))

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemName"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find3", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "ItemSize"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find4", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 10, "Quantity"))

        'value
        'cmd.Parameters("@val1").Value = CDate(Format(dtptemInDate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy"))
        cmd.Parameters("@val1").Value = dtptemInDate.Value.Date
        cmd.Parameters("@val2").Value = Trim(cbxtemInNewItem.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@val3").Value = Trim(cbxtemInNewItemSize.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@val4").Value = Val(txttemInNewQuantity.Text)


        ''SQL Where
        'type
                   'value

        ''Dim iString As String = "2005-05-05 22:12 PM"
        ''Dim oDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(lbltemInDate.Text, "MM-dd-yyyy", Nothing)
        ''MsgBox(oDate.ToString())
        Dim date1 As Date
        date1 = Date.Parse(Format("MM/dd/yyyy", lbltemInDate.Value))
        cmd.Parameters("@find1").Value = lbltemInDate.Value
        'CDate(Format(lbltemInDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy"))
        cmd.Parameters("@find2").Value = Trim(lbltemInItem.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@find3").Value = Trim(lbltemInItemSize.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@find4").Value = Val(lbltemInQuantity.Text)
```

Thanks LarsTech and Plutonix for the help

Comment: OleDB doesn't use named parameters.  Index order, so @val1 needs to be listed first, etc.

Comment: they *all* need to be added in the order they appear in the SQL

Comment: @LarsTech What do you mean? to be listed first

Comment: @Plutonix They are in order

Comment: Read your sql left to right, the first parameter is @val1, then @val2.  You need to add your `cmd.Parameters` in the same exact order.  Essentially, you can replace all of your parameter names with just a `?`.

Comment: No.  They appear in SQL in the order val1, val2, val3, val4... but youre adding the values for the `finds` first

Comment: I tried reordering them by following your advice ... but I still get the conversion from string to integer problem

Comment: Please [edit] your post to update it, we cannot see the screen from here

Comment: It looks like you are passing a string for the size parameter.  Try just:  `cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date))`

Comment: I would set the value at the same time to eliminate the other blocks: `cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@val1", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value=dtptemInDate.Value.Date`  You should also know that `Val` returns a Double, but the Quan col is integer

Comment: @LarsTech Same issue happens, do I need to format it first and parse? But before, I did that and same issue happens.

Comment: what kind of control is lbltemInDate?  a label or a DTP?

Comment: @Plutonix I tried your method same issue happens, ("@val1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date, "StockedDate").Value = dtptemInDate.Value.Date) ... conversion from string to int, it seems like it returns a string not a date

Comment: @LarsTech It looks like, i misunderstood what you meant your actually right at first I tried it on find1 not on val1 but the answer Plutonix gave a hint, Thanks guys